# Java generics <? super T>: not applicable methods

Tags: java, generics

I've this class:

```
public abstract class SlightExpression<T> extends Expression<T> {
    public BooleanExpression eq(Expression<? super T> right) {}
}
```

Go figure the next sentence:

```
    SlightExpression<?> left;
    SlightExpression<?> right;      
    //...

    left.eq(right);
```

Java is telling me:

```
The method eq(capture#19-of ?) in the type SlightExpression<capture#19-of ?> 
is not applicable for the arguments (SlightExpression<capture#20-of ?>)
```

However,

```
public abstract class StringExpression extends SlightExpression<String> {}
```

Then, Java is telling me nothing about it.

```
StringExpression s, f;
s.eq(f);
```

I don't understand this behaviour.

Comment: When declaring "SlightExpression<?> left" you need to pass in a Type as your declaration above. "<?>" mean that you don't know what it gonna be.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When left and right are declared as

```
SlightExpression<?> left;
SlightExpression<?> right;
```

You can assign to them `SlightExpression`s having different parameter types. For example :

```
left = new SlightExpression<Integer>();
right = new SlightExpression<String>();
```

Now, you can't pass a `SlightExpression<String>` to the `eq` method of a `SlightExpression<Integer>` instance.

On the other hand, in your second snippet, both instances are sub-classes of `SlightExpression<String>`, so there is no problem passing one instance as an argument to the `eq` method of the other instance.

To better understand the concept, you can apply it to better known classes. For example :

```
List<?> l1 = new ArrayList <String> ();
List<?> l2 = new ArrayList <Integer> ();
l1.addAll (l2); // this doesn't pass compilation, since you can't add Integer elements to
                // a List<String>

List<?> l1 = new ArrayList <String> ();
List<?> l2 = new ArrayList <String> ();
l1.addAll (l2); // this doesn't pass compilation too, since the compiler doesn't know that
                // l1 and l2 will refer to Lists of the same element type when addAll is 
                // invoked
```

On the other hand, this snippet will pass compilation, since the compiler sees that both Lists have the same element type :

```
List<String> l1 = new ArrayList <String> ();
List<String> l2 = new ArrayList <String> ();
l1.addAll (l2);
```